# WAMP after changing root‘s password, MYSQL and performance_schema database are gone

Tags: mysql, passwords, wamp

I installed WAMP with the default setting . Usually there are 4 default dbs in Mysql after it's installed. These are: information_schema, mysql,performance_schema and test.

But while I change the root's password with below method, mysql and performance_schema are dropped.

```
mysql>update user set password='test' where user='root'; 
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.06 sec) 
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0 

mysql> flush privileges ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec) 

mysql> quit ;
```

Then I restarted all the WAMP service, I　still don't need the password to login mysql. The worse thing is that mysql and performance_schema are gone.

It's so weird. I am sure no such sql is executed.

Can anybody help on this issue?  Besides, how to modify the root's password in WAMP.

Comment: How you login to `MySQL` ? Which user , password ?

Comment: @Abdul Manaf  I login via:  left click WAMP ICON->MySQL->mysql console.   The user/password is defaulted via root/<empty>